# Cross-Browser capture click/change of dropdown value with jQuery without a "Please Select" default option

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dropdown, onchange

I am looking for a cross-browser solution to a problem when I want to have this dropdown of categories where selecting a category will show/hide some dynamic content elsewhere on the page.

I'm trying to build it without having an ugly "Please Select" default option, however without this the behaviour of the dropdown is erratic.

```
<select class="categories">
<option value="invoicing">
   Invoicing
</option>
<option value="customisation">
   Customisation
</option>
...
</select>
```

My jQuery change handler:

```
$('.categories').on('change', function(e) {
   // show dynamic content based on dropdown selection
});
```

On Firefox this works with using both `click` and `change`, but on Chrome/Safari (Webkit) the event is triggered on first click of the dropdown **before the user has actually selected an option**.

This seems like a simple issue, but I can't find a workable solution to it (excluding the aforementioned 'Please Select' workaround)

Comment: `click` is not a practical event on `<select>` or `<option>` and never has been. Some browsers don't even register a click on `<option>`  Using `"change"` on `<select>` is the proper approach only and is universally supported

Comment: @charlietfl This is precisely my issue though. A `change` is not triggered unless the option is actually __changed__...so the first option, if selected, does not trigger this event.

Comment: Ok...you can trigger change event on page load also ... `$('.categories').on('change', function(e) {/* do stuff*/}).change();`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the comment, but I am confused why I would want to do that. I am looking for a way for the `change` event to be triggered when a user selects "Invoicing" from the list. Surely triggering a `change` event on page load would prematurely show the dynamic content that I mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Chrome can work fine with your code.
You can see your code from the below link:

https://jsfiddle.net/br6dv2uL/

Comment: Well without an empty one the default value of a `<select>` becomes the first `<option>` and if it has no `value` the text of that option is the value used. So there is no way for a user to change to the first one if there is no empty one. One of the quirks that has caused numerous select replacement modules to be created over the years

Comment: @TheKNVB Thanks for the comment, but your fiddle exhibits the exact behaviour I am reporting. If you select "Invoicing" then there is no entry in the console.

Comment: Also a user won't try to chose one that is already showing

Comment: When I run your code on firefox, the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Look here will see the default value is already set as first option https://jsfiddle.net/9qhjcy14/ So there is no way to re-select it without selecting something else first

Comment: @charlietfl This is a fair point, I think i'll just leave an empty dropdown option at the top. It seems like i'm possibly screwing with the UX trying to get this working and perhaps a simple empty option would solve this problem altogether. Admittedly, it won't look very pleasing on the eye.

Comment: If there is logic involved based on that first value .... triggering the initial change on page load is a common approach as I did above. User won't change it if it is the value they already want

Comment: @charlietfl What I was really looking for was a way to say "if a user actually clicks this option then trigger the change event". But it looks like this is not possible as jQuery will not see the option as "changed" if it hasn't deviated from the default option shown on page load (the first `<option>`). I'm curious to know more about this idea of triggering it on page load because the way that would work right now is it would show a section of text specific to that option which the user may or may not be looking for.

Comment: Example that shows content based on <select>  value and triggers on page load https://jsfiddle.net/ky2v9q3a/